# What is the reason to use redux on react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Have anybody a good reason to use redux on react? I was thinking to build very small components in react, so i don't need redux.
Every component has his own state like redux.

What do you think? What kind of experience do you have?

Answer (score 6):

Great paragraph from [the Redux FAQs](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/General.html#general-when-to-use):

> Pete Hunt, one of the early contributors to React, says:
>
> > You'll know when you need Flux. If you aren't sure if you need it, you
> >     don't need it.
>
> Similarly, Dan Abramov, one of the creators of Redux, says:
>
> > I would like to amend this: don't use Redux until you have problems
> >     with vanilla React.
>
> In general, use Redux when you have reasonable amounts of data
>   changing over time, you need a single source of truth, and you find
>   that approaches like keeping everything in a top-level React
>   component's state are no longer sufficient.
>
> However, it's also important to understand that using Redux comes with
>   tradeoffs. It's not designed to be the shortest or fastest way to
>   write code. It's intended to help answer the question "When did a
>   certain slice of state change, and where did the data come from?",
>   with predictable behavior. It does so by asking you to follow specific
>   constraints in your application: store your application's state as
>   plain data, describe changes as plain objects, and handle those
>   changes with pure functions that apply updates immutably. This is
>   often the source of complaints about "boilerplate". These constraints
>   require effort on the part of a developer, but also open up a number
>   of additional possibilities (such as store persistence and
>   synchronization).
>
> If you're just learning React, you should probably focus on thinking
>   in React first, then look at Redux once you better understand React
>   and how Redux might fit into your application.
>
> In the end, Redux is just a tool. It's a great tool, and there's some
>   great reasons to use it, but there's also reasons you might not want
>   to use it. Make informed decisions about your tools, and understand
>   the tradeoffs involved in each decision.

Answer (score 2):

Redux is mainly used for application state management. In an application done in  Redux the state of an entire application in a single immutable state object, which cannot change directly by your react component.

Instead react components can emit actions, which are passed to reducer/s which will change the state.

You definitely do not need to use Redux if you design a single component. You could consider Redux for more complex applications.